# Can someone explain this Mudra being done by Ramakrishna Paramhansa in Samadhi?

Tags: shiva, yoga, vivekananda, ramakrishna, mudra

[image]

> "Ramakrishna in bhava samadhi at the house of Keshab Chandra Sen. He
>   is seen supported by his nephew Hriday and surrounded by brahmo
>   devotees."

Can any scholar here, identify this hand Mudra done by Ramakrishna Paramhans by his right hand and its importance in Yog and Samadhi?

The same Mudra can be seen in Lord Shiva's left middle hand as well.**Is it superior to Gyan Mudra for Samadhi?**

[image]

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Its known as Mriga-Mudra and is related to Lord Shiva.Yes, the Apaana mudra also looks the same.

Answer (score 2):

[image]That is known as the Mriga-Mudra.That is mentioned in the dhyana-Mantra of Lord Shiva:

> dhaayet nityam mahesham rajatagirinivam chaaru-chandra-avatamsham/ ratna-aakalpa-ujjvalangam prasu-**mriga**-vara-abhiti hastam prasannam/padma-aasinam samantaat stutam amarganair bhyaghrakrittim vasanam/vishvadyam visvavijam bhavabhayaharam panchavaktram trinetram --Reference :Stavakusumanjali,Udbodhan.

Normally mind is compared with a running deer and this mudra signifies keeping the mind still in case of Lord Shiva, as He holds parashu (axe) in other hand that signifies slaying the deer ie calming the mind.

But Sri Ramakrishna so far as I know did not use any such mudra intentionally.All was the effect of divine ecstacy.But it looks like Mriga-Mudra. The question of superiority or inferiority does not aruse by the way,Only Lord Shiva, known as the Pasupati (Mriga is a Pashu) has Mriga-Mudra in His hand.
The image enclosed by you is a retouched one.I am enclosing a copy of the original for your perusal.

Comment: what about Mudra in left hand, that is of 2 fingers up?

Comment: @Nitin thats known to none.As I wrote, His mudras were spontaneous.

Comment: @Nitin BTW the one of left hand is seen in His other photographs also.

Comment: His left hand mudra is same as of Jesus Christ is depicted in his pictures, http://www.jesuschristsavior.net/Jesus.html and must be some special Mudra.

Comment: @Nitin But we do not have any photograph of Jesus and so its an artist's imagination.

Comment: But we do have image of Ramakrishna Paramhans's left hand, i am more curious to know about that mudra of Samadhi.

Comment: @Nitin in the question you asked about that of the right hand which is similar with that of Lord Shiva,None knows the meaning of the left hand mudra

Comment: Go through the 18-30 minute section of the You Tube video given in one of the answers.  There seems to be 2 opinions. First opinion is that the right hand mudra is Mrga mudra as given in this answer. The left hand Mudra is known as Alapadma Mudra (Fully bloomed lotus). The other opinion is that the right hand and the left hand mudras together consist of Kurma Mudra.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but a nice explanation is given in this talk here https://youtu.be/AEXaZTxg7vc

Comment: The explanation of this photograph is given after 18 minute and continues to about 30 minutes.

Comment: There seems to be 2 opinions. First opinion is that the right hand mudra is Mrga mudra. The left hand Mudra is known as Alapadma Mudra (Fully bloomed lotus). The other opinion is that the right hand and the left hand mudras together consist of Kurma Mudra.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.